# Discord JS Как создать приглашение и сохранить его в переменную?

Tags: javascript, discord

Как создать приглашение на сервер и сохранить в переменную?

```
let newinvite
message.channel.createInvite({temporary : true})
.then(inv => newinvite = inv.code);
```

Не работает, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Покажу интересную штучку:

```js
let newInvite = await message.channel.createInvite({ temporary: true }).then(inv => inv);
```

Это запишет в переменную `newInvite` код приглашения